# Colour bar for contour 2D graph

Tags: graphics, color, legending

How could I plot the colour legend for my 2D contour graph

```
ListContourPlot[
  arrayData, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], 
  ContourStyle -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Rs", "Rd"}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Automatic
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please publish (at least a small part of) your arrayData. Otherwise we cannot try and see, how we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you add a color legend to your `ListContourPlot` (also true for similar types of plots). This is by the way the third example in the [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) documentation. Of course, the crucial part is the `PlotLegends` option.

```
data = Table[{x = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], y = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], Sin[x y]}, 1000}];
ListContourPlot[
 data,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
 ContourStyle -> None,
 FrameLabel -> {"Rs", "Rd"},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *Mathematica* version 9.0 or later, you can use the `PlotLegends` option as shown in the documentation and in Lukas's answer (beat me to it by 2 minutes).

But if you are using an older version you have to resort to the `PlotLegends` package (I know it's confusing),

```
<< PlotLegends`
With[{arrayData = Array[Sin[.01 π (#1 - 2 #2)] &, {100, 100}]},
  ShowLegend[
   ListContourPlot[arrayData,
     ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
     ContourStyle -> None,
     FrameLabel -> {"Rs", "Rd"},
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     PlotRange -> Automatic],
  {ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", 
   LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}]
  ]
```

[image]